# Empty JPanel not positioning correctly in relation to other JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am using swing to build a GUI with 4 JPanels inside a JPanel using the BorderLayout manager:

1. A row of labels
2. A column of JButtons
3. A display area (it is a class that extends JPanel and has nothing added to it and is used as a drawing area)
4. Another column of buttons

My code looks like this:

```
    JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    middle.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    middle.add(midLabels,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    middle.add(pickupButtons,BorderLayout.WEST);
    middle.add(simulation,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    middle.add(dropButtons,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The simulation panel is just an extended JPanel that overrides paintComponent to draw an image. The problem is, the simulation area is on the left and not in the middle:

[image: The wrong layout]

What I actually want is:

[image]

Edit, here is an example, do I need to use a different layout manager to get the empty JPanel positioned correctly?:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test extends JFrame {  
    final static int MAXFLOORS = 8;
    public Test() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Simulator");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel simulation = new JPanel();
        JPanel dropButtons = new JPanel();
        JPanel pickupButtons = new JPanel();

        pickupButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(MAXFLOORS, 1));
        dropButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(MAXFLOORS, 1));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());      
        add(simulation,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(dropButtons,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(pickupButtons,BorderLayout.WEST);

        for (int i = MAXFLOORS; i != 0; i--) {
            JButton pb = new JButton("F" + i);
            dropButtons.add(pb);

            JButton db = new JButton("F" + i);
            dropButtons.add(db);
        }       
        repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - did you have a question?

Comment: Random question, have you tried changing the order that you add the components?

Comment: It looks like you may have (inadvertently) added `pickupButtons` to `dropButtons`.

Comment: That reminds me of the Russian chauffeur for the "Tappet" brothers' Click and Clack radio show, Mr. Pikop Andropov.

Comment: and out of my curiosity there are two way with or without GlassPane / JLayer

Comment: @dann.dev That didn't fix it. Andrew: my question is what I might have done wrong. I will attach my code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
    for (int i = MAXFLOORS; i != 0; i--) {
        final JButton pb = new JButton("F" + i);
        dropButtons.add(pb);

        final JButton db = new JButton("F" + i);
        dropButtons.add(db);
    }
```

You're adding onto `dropButtons` twice, instead of `pickupButtons`.